# Duplicates getting inserted in database when calling the server in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, database, xamarin, server

I'm facing an issue in my application where I send the server request once and receive a single response but my request has created duplicate rows in the database. The only primary key in the database table is the row id which gets incremented every time a request is sent so duplicate rows of values get created with different row ids. I'm using Xamarin Android. Could you please let me know if this issue is a bug related to Xamarin and if they is any way in which this can be fixed?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

This is my code:

I call this method in my OnCreate()

```
    public void SendMobileNo(Activity activity)
    {
        Services_GetValue.GetValue client = new Services_GetValue.GetValue();

        Services_GetValue.GetValueRequest request = new Services_GetValue.GetValueRequest()
        {
            key = "abac",
            PhoneNo = "1234567890"
        };

        client.BeginCheckPhone(request, (ar) => {
            Services_GetValue.GetValueResponse response = client.EndCheckPhone(ar);
            this.IsPhoneValid = response.IsValidPhoneNo;

            activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                if (SendMobileNoCompleted != null)
                {

                    this.SendMobileNoCompleted();

                    this.SendMobileNoCompleted = null;
                }
            });


        }, null);


        client.CheckPhone(request);

    }
```

I have created a Proxy in WebReferences package with the name "Services_GetValue.GetValue" and it is a SOAP webservice.

Comment: We would need to see way more information than this. How are you communicating with the server, what code are you using, what does the server code look like? Even if this were related to some error with Xamarin, I'm not sure how you are communicating with your service to even make that connection.

Comment: Like Kevin Ford said there is  not enough information to go on but in general I do not think this is a Xamarin bug. If Xamarin were always sending duplicate calls on service calls this would be a much more visible question posted five years ago. If you are certain you are only calling the service once and getting one response then start looking through the insert code on the server.